# sqlite optimal update after an alter table add

Tags: sqlite, optimization, sql-update

I have a process where at some point I got to add a new column to a table of type INTEGER, then I got to populate this new column with an UPDATE. I do this in C.

I can lean down my code to

```
CREATE table t (a integer, b integer)
populate t
CREATE INDEX t_ndx on t (a)
ALTER TABLE t add c integer
```

The C pseudo code to update the column 'c' look like this

```
sqlite3_stmt u;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "update t set c=? where a=?, -1, &u, 0);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{ c=c_a[i];
  a=a_a[i];
  sqlite3_bind_int64(u, 1, c);
  sqlite3_bind_int64(u, 1, a);
  sqlite3_step(u);
}
```

The order of a's are the same for this UPDATE as the one given when t was created.

I'd like to know if the sqlite3 engine detect the 'sequential' access and do speed up  the "where a=?" (i.e keep a kind of caching of previous cursor ?

I'd like to know as well if there are 'hidden' feature like binding array's (at least when dealing witn INTEGERs) to avoid construct such a loop and avoid all those bindings and avoid the bytecode for doing all those insert something along the line of

```
sqlite3_stmt u;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "update t set c=? where a=?, -1, &u, 0);
sqlite3_bind_int64_array(u, 1, c_a, n);
sqlite3_bind_int64_array(u, 1, a_a, n);
sqlite3_step_array(u,n);
```

Thanx in advance
Cheers
Phi

Answer (score 2):

Your code already is pretty much optimal. Searching for the row by `a` needs a single index lookup and a single table row lookup; both will be fast because the needed pages are likely to be already cached.

You could speed up the lookup on `a` by making this column the [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), but this makes sense only if `a` actually is the primary key.

In theory, it would be possible to update multiple rows at once:

```
UPDATE t
SET c = CASE a
        WHEN :a1 THEN :c1
        WHEN :a2 THEN :c2
        WHEN :a2 THEN :c3
        END
WHERE a IN (:a1, :a2, :a3);
```

But for many `a` values, this is likely to be implemented as a scan over the table, so it would make sense only if you could fit all values into the query, which is not possible for a large table.

Comment: Thanx CL for your reply, I'll keep the CASE example for another situation I got. I created an INDEX on 'a' in the hope it will speed up the WHERE a=?, I thought it would make the scan easier, yet the =? order I will provide exactly match the row order in 't', may be I could then force the scan by rowid, if the scan by rowid is faster than the scan by index on col 'a'. I don't know the internals of sqlite3. Again thanx. Phi